# Image Path is scrambled when sent as an email template

Tags: html, image, email, gmail

I created an email template and everything works correctly except for the images. Image links are always scrambled. I tried to search for this error and got the idea that my server images might not be public. so I uploaded my images to google drive, turned on the image sharing and pasted link as src attribute but it still gives me broken image.

```
 <img align="center" alt="Image" border="0" class="center autowidth" src="https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipN7nO024WiqXwljlKtjBnAmYibqu-qbON2f-o6V" style="text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; border: none; width: 100%; max-width: 142px; display: block;" title="Image" width="142"/>
```

This is the resulting link I am getting in gmail

```
<img align="center" alt="Image" border="0" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2O2l92Xpr3J2mn0fQCZcsCj5_HgubYMC5Yjs126neCu8NpIeGbJhVtx5AgWQDBb1Rzucm9OyHEvAaV1764ZREH3uUB8GovbKgx4k2TrbLLCR9CHNFFTTb5L9wNibIDk=s0-d-e1-ft#https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipN7nO024WiqXwljlKtjBnAmYibqu-qbON2f-o6V" style="text-decoration:none;height:auto;border:none;width:100%;max-width:142px;display:block" title="Image" width="142" class="CToWUd">
```

How do I solve this?

What I actually want here is to use the images stored in my google drive or google photos instead of using my own website's server. Is that Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a pretty simple and straight forward way of this. Upload you image to an image hosting site ( the one I used is [imgur.com](https://imgur.com/)). You might need to create an account, then upload the image then you will find a direct link to that image. Use that link in your email template and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by google proxy servers that are caching the content. Quick search found this:

[Email thumbnail URL changed to googleusercontent.com in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471607/email-thumbnail-url-changed-to-googleusercontent-com-in-gmail/51643787)

[Gmail's new image caching is breaking image links in newsletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903967/gmails-new-image-caching-is-breaking-image-links-in-newsletter/20983555)

There are solutions provided there that could work for you.

Comment: Yes I took some ideas from there earlier. My images are in png format, also tried to change the URL so that it won't contain any query like structure and other things but it still is not showing