# Why Odoo 15 emails do not show images?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

When I open an email sent from Odoo, it does not show any images:

[image]

If I inspect the link of the image, I see:

`https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/qSpzzzb6JaHXBEBtLfInNbNx6mQNl7odluv4KBqJaH1ZtoWPvGde60Bsprd7wy0WY5-7xgiZ9PJtkKtwvNA=s0-d-e1-ft#http://myip:myport/logo.png?company=1`

If I paste that link on a new tab, I get a 404. However, if I paste the substring:

`http://myip:myport/logo.png?company=1`

I see the main company logo.

I have only one database running in the instance. I am using the IP `http://myip:myport` to access Odoo so far. I have that IP `http://myip:myport` set in the parameter `web.base.url`. I also have `web.base.url` set to True and `report.url` set to `http://127.0.0.1:myport`, although I think both have nothing to do here.

I've googled about this problem for hours, but the solution is not very clear.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem or have any idea of what can be happening?

Comment: When calling the URL from substring do you have an ongoing Odoo session (are you logged in on the used browser)? If so try using this link without being logged in, for example in a private/inkognito browser window.

Comment: With no Odoo session opened, and from a browser incognito window, I can see the company logo image using the link substring.

Comment: Looks like a browser caching problem to me.

Comment: But it doesn't matter if I'm logged in or I'm opening an incognito window, the image link in the received mail drives to a 404. That shouldn't be a browser caching problem, should it?

Comment: No, then it's not a caching problem.

Comment: I think that's related to Google’s secure proxy servers. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51643787/4891717). You may have to add your Odoo server address to the Google whitelist in some way that I don't know. Let me now if you make it work ! Does it happen sending the email to other accounts different from Gmail?