PHP Mail() - external images are broken in Gmail, Outlook and iPhone work as expected
I have a pretty straightforward mail script that is sending fine, but inline images appear broken only in Gmail. Outlook is fine and the Mail app on my phone works as well. It's just when I open Gmail in my browser that it's broken and if I inspect it, it has a long string appended to the path, but if I remove that it works. There's no "display images" option anywhere when I open the email. So how can I get it work in Gmail?
I've looked around a lot and can't quite find what I'm looking for.
Here's the script:
$to      = 'email@example.com';
$subject = 'Welcome to the Playtest Program';

$message = '<img src="https://example.com/maxent-email_logo.png" /><br /><br />';
// ...rest of body content

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// send
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo '<h1>mail sent</h2>';
}else{
    echo '<h1>mail NOT sent</h2>';
}


What is the "long string"? This sounds like a protection against pixel tracking.

@Barmar https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/meips/ADKq_Nah5I_oel_yOaynOVvF7SZ4YpDZ7_4bXSP3Cn_7MY2RQrtH4XECl7l13sMiTlvO6r9Kw_VhuvFGom6phqtUlmCHDA=s0-d-e1-ft# followed by the actual path to the image

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471607/email-thumbnail-url-changed-to-googleusercontent-com-in-gmail

@Barmar So I need to whitelist it? It wants me to create an admin account

Only if your site has code that prevents Google from caching the image.

It's running through CloudFlare but just with the standard rules. Maybe I'll try contacting the hosting and see if there's anything on their end

@Barmar I just tried adding some random images from the same domain I'm trying to pull the logo from and they show up in just fine. I double checked the path and it's correct

@Barmar Got it working! I can't answer my own question since it's been closed. BUT turns out it was my hosting blocking it. Not sure what the criteria was because it seemed random, but I've added a rule excluding UA GoogleImageProxy and that solved it
