# How to embed images in a symfony mail?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-mailer

So I designed an email template for my reset-password system.
In the email templates, there are Images (logo).

I placed those images inside a folder called `Email_Images` and that folder is placed inside the `Public` folder!

First, I  tried to link the images using `Asset()` twig Function like this:

```
<img alt="logo 1" src="{{asset('Email_Images/1.png')}}" />
<img alt="logo 2" src="{{asset('Email_Images/2.jpg')}}" />
```

But none of them works. So I tried to get the image in the controller and send it to the template, like this :

```
 $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
        ->from(new Address('myEmail@gmail.com', 'My Subject'))
        ->to($user->getEmail())
        ->subject('Your password reset request');

        $img= $email ->embed(fopen('Email_Images/1.jpg', 'r'), 'img');

        $email->htmlTemplate('reset_password/email.html.twig')
        ->context([
            'resetToken' => $resetToken,

            'img' => $img,

            'tokenLifetime' => $this->resetPasswordHelper->getTokenLifetime(),
        ]);
```

In the template I did

```
<img alt="logo 1" src="{{ img }}" />
```

and I get this error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
> ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
> Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail could not be converted to
> string").

What is the right way to add/embed an image in an Email?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of getting the images in the controller and sending them to the twig page.
You can do this :

First, Define a Twig namespace (called `img` for example) that points to the folder where the images are stored in. In this case, the folder is called `Email_Images`

Add those lines to `config/packages/twig.yaml`

```
twig:
    # ...

    paths:
        # point this wherever your images live
        '%kernel.project_dir%/public/Email_Images': img
```

Now you can use `email.image()` twig function to embed the images inside the email.

```
<img src="{{ email.image('@img/1.png') }}" alt="Logo">
```

Comment: But does this not generate an url like `C:\dev\myawesomeproject\public\Email_Images\1.png`. So it will be a local path? This solution won't work if you are sending these emails to users which don't have the image in that exact same path. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't generate that URL but it reference images using the syntax `cid:` [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#mailer-twig-embedding-images)

Answer (score 2):

`{{ asset('Email_Images/1.png') }}` will result in a relative URL like `/Email_Images/1.png`. But for e-mails you need an absolute URL which you can generate like this `<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('Email_Images/1.png')) }}"/>`. Because the e-mail does not know anything about your domain name.

Furthermore I recommend you to configure the following [parameters](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/console/request_context.html#configuring-the-request-context-globally) (if you are going to send e-mails via console commands, too):

```
router.request_context.host:     example.com    # your domain
router.request_context.scheme:   http           # your scheme http or https
asset.request_context.base_path: '%router.request_context.base_url%'
asset.request_context.secure:    true
```

Comment: Even after using the `absolute_url()` function and setting those parameters in services.yaml. It still doesnt work .

Comment: Does the image simply not apear or is there any other error than a 404? And what happens if you call the generated url in your browser? And what happens if you call the correct URL in your browser? How does they differentiate? Which program do you use to read your e-mails?

Comment: I am recieving/reading those emails on my Gmail account. I did `<h1> {{ absolute_url(asset('Email_Images/1.png')) }} </h1>` too see what it returns.. and the results are http://127.0.0.1:8000/Email_Images/1.png

Comment: I see, have a look at the explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/20837071/5947371 why this not works. I would recomment you to use [mailhog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) for your local development to test emails.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I send emails from website AND emails from cron tasks. For emails sent from the website it's fine to use `absolute_url(asset(...))`, but cron tasks don't know about your domaine name.

So to make things simple, my trick is to define the domaine name as a .env variable, and then :

in `.env`

```
DOMAIN_NAME=https://mywebsite.com
```

in `config/package/twig.yaml`

```
twig:
    ...
    globals:
        DOMAIN_NAME: '%env(DOMAIN_NAME)%'
```

in `templates/emails/reset-password.email.twig` *(or base.email.twig)*

```
<img src="{{ DOMAIN_NAME ~ asset('images/logo.jpg') }}" alt="logo">
```